# OAuth 2 - Custom Attributes like SAML

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, saml-2.0

SAML supports just in time provisioning with custom user attributes to be passed as part of SAML assertion after successful login, wondering OAuth2 supports anything similar ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SAML is an authentication protocol, OAuth 2.0 is not. This means that OAuth 2.0 and SAML cannot be compared in the way you suggest since OAuth 2.0 does not pass attributes about a user who has just authenticated.

On top of that, Just-In-Time (JIT) provisioning is rather independent of SAML and not part of the SAML protocol specifications. The fact that SAML sends across user attributes in an assertion can be leveraged to implement a JIT provisioning system on top of, but that is a local implementation choice, not a SAML feature.

But, one could build the same JIT system on top of OpenID Connect, which is a user authentication protocol built on top of OAuth 2.0. That would be comparable to JIT with SAML.